# How to enable Java 12 preview features with Gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, build.gradle, java-12

When I tried to build my Java code which has [switch expressions](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/354) using Gradle, it throws this error:

```
error: switch expressions are a preview feature and are disabled by default.
```

I tried running `./gradlew build --enable-preview` which didn't work either.

I'm using Gradle 5.3.1.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You need to configure the `JavaCompile` tasks, so that Gradle passes this option to the Java compiler when compiling.

Something like this should work:

```
tasks.withType(JavaCompile).each {
    it.options.compilerArgs.add('--enable-preview')
}
```

To run the app/tests we need to add `jvmArgs`.

Example:

```
test {
    jvmArgs(['--enable-preview'])
}
```

Comment: also if I have to run the app or run the tests, I've to add this `test {
    jvmArgs(['--enable-preview'])
} run {
    jvmArgs(['--enable-preview'])
}`

Comment: Since I include the [application plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html), I use `applicationDefaultJvmArgs += ["--enable-preview"]` instead of `test {jvmArgs(['--enable-preview'])}`.

Answer (score 30):

Currently there seem not to be a single place for defining that. You should do it for all of the task types (compile, test runtime or java exec related tasks). I found myself fully covered with:

```
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.compilerArgs += "--enable-preview"
}

tasks.withType(Test) {
    jvmArgs += "--enable-preview"
}

tasks.withType(JavaExec) {
    jvmArgs += '--enable-preview'
}
```

Comment: The `JavaExec` part is useful for Spring Boot application for example.

Comment: yes for `bootRun` but also useful when you use the simple `application` plugin.

Comment: For Kotlin DSL (when you write build config in `*.gradle.kts` files): use `tasks.withType<JavaExec>().configureEach { jvmArgs("--enable-preview")}`

Answer (score 15):

Here is another version using the Gradle Kotlin DSL for usage in `build.gradle.kts`:

```
plugins {
    `java-library`
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_12
}

tasks.withType<JavaCompile> {
    options.compilerArgs.add("--enable-preview")
}
tasks.test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    jvmArgs("--enable-preview")
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.4.2")
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.4.2")
}
```