# WhatsApp4j - Api | Does not compile because class uses preview features

Tags: java, whatsapp, preview-feature

I wanted to try out the (https://github.com/Auties00/WhatsappWeb4j) Whatsapp4j library,
my gradle:

```
        plugins {
        id 'java'
    }
    
    group 'de.test'
    version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
    
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.auties00:whatsappweb4j:2.2.1'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.1'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.1'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

I only added it to my gradle file, and when I run my Main.java (which only implements an class of this library)

```
  import it.auties.whatsapp4j.whatsapp.WhatsappAPI;
    
    public class Main {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        }
    }
```

I receive this error:

> ```
> error: classfile for
> C:\Users\User\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.github.auties00\whatsappweb4j\2.2.1b3c7842cc489e3ae0cc6147c84b11ff6334671e\whatsappweb4j-2.2.1.jar(/it/auties/whatsapp4j/whatsapp/WhatsappAPI.class)
> uses preview features of Java SE 16.
> ```

I tried to fix it setting my language level to preview (I don't rly know what preview features are) :
[image: https://prnt.sc/1uaay97]
but sadly that didn't work. The error remained.
I hope someone knows how to fix it.

-I use IntelliJ IDEA

Comment: Several preview features are in JDK 17 not preview anymore. Try to use 17...

Comment: @30thh That won't work, the problem is the library the OP is using, which was compiled for Java 16 with preview features enabled. This means it can only be used on Java 16 with preview features enabled, and not on any other Java version.

Comment: If you're still running Java 16, you probably need to enable preview features in your Gradle build file. For example, see [How to enable Java 12 preview features with Gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55433883/how-to-enable-java-12-preview-features-with-gradle)

Comment: Yep that worked thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Mark Rotteveel pointed out enabling preview features in the Gradle build file worked.

[How to enable Java 12 preview features with Gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55433883/how-to-enable-java-12-preview-features-with-gradle)

adding this works.

```
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.compilerArgs += "--enable-preview"
}

tasks.withType(Test) {
    jvmArgs += "--enable-preview"
}

tasks.withType(JavaExec) {
    jvmArgs += '--enable-preview'
}
```